# requestAccessToAccounts not performing in Xcode9

Tags: swift, twitter

I have an app that uses a Twitter project to access tweets. It worked fine in Xcode 8 simulators but when I tried to run it on my device which is using iOS 11.2.1, I have problems. Also, using XCode9 simulators is causing the same issue. The app is not asking for permission to access Twitter with a popup like it was before. The following code handles the request:

```
    func performTwitterSLRequest(_ request: SLRequest, handler: @escaping (PropertyList?) -> Void) {
    if let account = twitterAccount {
        request.account = account
        request.perform { (jsonResponse, httpResponse, _) in
            var propertyListResponse: PropertyList?
            if jsonResponse != nil {
                propertyListResponse = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonResponse!, options: .mutableLeaves)
                if propertyListResponse == nil {
                    let error = "Couldn't parse JSON response."
                    self.log(error)
                    propertyListResponse = error
                }
            } else {
                let error = "No response from Twitter."
                self.log(error)
                propertyListResponse = error
            }
            self.synchronize {
                self.captureFollowonRequestInfo(propertyListResponse)
            }
            handler(propertyListResponse)
        }
    } else {
        let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
        let twitterAccountType = accountStore.accountType(withAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)
        accountStore.requestAccessToAccounts(with: twitterAccountType, options: nil) { (granted, _) in
            if granted {
                if let account = accountStore.accounts(with: twitterAccountType)?.last as? ACAccount {
                    twitterAccount = account
                    self.performTwitterSLRequest(request, handler: handler)
                } else {
                    let error = "Couldn't discover Twitter account type."
                    self.log(error)
                    handler(error)
                }
            } else {
                let error = "Access to Twitter was not granted."
                self.log(error)
                handler(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am just getting: "Access to Twitter was not granted." Has requestAccessToAccounts been deprecated or could there be another cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, support for accessing Twitter (or Facebook, etc) accounts using the ACAccount framework has been removed as of iOS 11.

Per the [release notes](https://bjtechnews.org/2017/06/release-notes-for-ios-11-build-15a5278f/) for iOS 11 build 15a5278f:

> Social accounts have been removed from Settings in iOS 11. Third-party apps will no longer have access to those signed-in accounts.

Twitter has [posted a note](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Migrating-from-iOS-Social-Framework) on how to work around this using their TwitterKit framework. However, they've recently (April 2018) announced that they are [discontinuing support for it](https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html). You may need to look for other (ie. open source) options for this, as it should be still possible using their API.